# Tried to implement Batch processing while invoking a transform module?

Tags: marklogic, java

I want to batch process a set of documents using MarkLogic Java Client Api. I followed below [documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/resourceservices#id_84134) to invoke a JavaScript module.

```
   import com.marklogic.client.DatabaseClient;
import com.marklogic.client.DatabaseClientFactory;
import com.marklogic.client.datamovement.ApplyTransformListener;
import com.marklogic.client.datamovement.ApplyTransformListener.ApplyResult;
import com.marklogic.client.datamovement.DataMovementManager;
import com.marklogic.client.datamovement.JobTicket;
import com.marklogic.client.datamovement.QueryBatcher;
import com.marklogic.client.datamovement.WriteBatcher;
import com.marklogic.client.document.JSONDocumentManager;
import com.marklogic.client.document.ServerTransform;
import com.marklogic.client.io.DOMHandle;
import com.marklogic.client.query.StructuredQueryBuilder;

public class rest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DatabaseClient client = DatabaseClientFactory.newClient
                ("localhost", port, "x", "x",  DatabaseClientFactory.Authentication.DIGEST);

        final DataMovementManager manager = client.newDataMovementManager();

          // Build query
        final StructuredQueryBuilder query = client
          .newQueryManager()
          .newStructuredQueryBuilder();

        // Specify a server-side transformation module (stored procedure) by name
        ServerTransform transform = new ServerTransform("restone-tsm");
        ApplyTransformListener transformListener = new ApplyTransformListener()
          .withTransform(transform)
          .withApplyResult(ApplyResult.REPLACE) // Transform in-place, i.e. rewrite
          .onSuccess(batch -> {})
          .onSkipped(batch -> {})
          .onBatchFailure((batch, throwable) -> {});

        // Apply the transformation to only the documents that match a query.
        // In this case, those in the “raw” collection.
        final QueryBatcher batcher = manager
          .newQueryBatcher(query.collection("accounts"));
        batcher
        .withBatchSize(1000)
        .withThreadCount(16)
          .onUrisReady(transformListener)
          .onQueryFailure(exception -> exception.printStackTrace());
        final JobTicket ticket = manager.startJob(batcher);
        batcher.awaitCompletion();
        manager.stopJob(ticket);
        }
            }
```

As you suggested changed my transform module(i.e.`restone-tsm`)

```
   function harmonize(context, params, content)
{ 
  var transformed = {};
  transformed.Metadata = { "Source" : "International"};
  transformed.Canonical= {"Future" : "Element"};
  transformed.Source = content;
  xdmp.documentInsert(fn.concat("/transformed/", fn.baseUri(content)), transformed, {collections : "transform"});
};
exports.transform = harmonize;
```

It got executed successfully. But as you suggested in comment to apply `cts.uris` in the `query batcher` i checked for that function in `StructuredQueryBuilder` but didn't find any. But the above code worked fine.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you need to extract the cts:uris() query logic from your transform module and apply it in a QueryBatcher, then have each of the selected docs transformed with the transform module (that expects to transform a single document from the content parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a separate [`ServerEvaluationCall`](https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/eval/ServerEvaluationCall.html), use an [`ApplyTransformListener`](https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/eval/ServerEvaluationCall.html) with your batcher, as described in [Applying an In-Database Transformation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/data-movement#id_51555):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  DatabaseClient client = DatabaseClientFactory.newClient
            ("localhost", pwd, "x", "x",  DatabaseClientFactory.Authentication.DIGEST);

  ServerTransform txform = new ServerTransform("tsm"); 

  QueryManager qm = client.newQueryManager();
  StructuredQueryBuilder query = qm.newStructuredQueryBuilder();
  query.collection();

  DataMovementManager dmm = client.newDataMovementManager();
  QueryBatcher batcher = dmm.newQueryBatcher(query);
  batcher.withBatchSize(5)
         .withThreadCount(3)
         .withConsistentSnapshot()
         .onUrisReady(
           new ApplyTransformListener().withTransform(txform))
         .onBatchSuccess(batch-> {
                   System.out.println(
                       batch.getTimestamp().getTime() +
                       " documents written: " +
                       batch.getJobWritesSoFar());
         })
         .onBatchFailure((batch,throwable) -> {
           throwable.printStackTrace();
         });

  // start the job and feed input to the batcher
  dmm.startJob(batcher);

  batcher.awaitCompletion();
  dmm.stopJob(batcher);
  client.release();
}
```

You need to ensure that your [transform module](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/transforms#id_77476) has a function that implements the required interface and is exports it with the name `transform`, and is [installed](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/transforms#id_67722) on the server.

Adjust the logic in your transform not to perform the URIs query (that will be handled by the QueryBatcher), so that it expects to transform the `content`.

```
function harmonize(context, params, content)
{ 
  var transformed = {};
  transformed.Metadata = { "Source" : "International"};
  transformed.Canonical= {"Future" : "Element"};
  transformed.Source = content;
  xdmp.documentInsert(fn.concat("/transformed", fn.baseUri(content)), transformed, {collections : "transform"});
};
exports.transform = harmonize;
```

Comment: Thanks @Hansen, but `.withConsistentSnapshot(),.onUrisReady()` were not methods of `writebatcher`. So instead i tried with  `query batcher` but it requires query as an input, but in my case i don't need any query so it was not accepting .

Comment: whoops, I was stitching that together without the assistance of an IDE and had conflated QueryBatcher with WriteBatcher. I believe that it should be `.withTransform()` for a WriteBatcher and remove the `.withConsistentSnapshot()`. I have updated the example code

Comment: @Hansen, With updated code i can able to run the module but the transformation is not talking place i updated my question . But the same transform module worked through `ServerEvaluationCall` .

Comment: I had updated the latest code with my assumptions. The code worked fine for me but want to check if this is what you had suggested in above comment.